# Piping parsed remote JSON to response

Tags: json, node.js, express, stream

I have a node server that makes a request to another node server which returns JSON which I want to parse and then send as a response.

I realize that the extra parse step is unnecessary, but I want to make sure I'm understanding the usage of streams properly:

```
http.get({host: config.host, path: "/data"}, function (response) {
    response.pipe(JSONStream.parse()).pipe(routeResponse);
});
```

However this gives me:

> http.js:853
>       throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');

If I just do `response.pipe(routeResponse)` it does work.  Once again, I know this is unnecessary, but I want to get it working.

Additionally:

1. How would I set the response header independently (if necessary)
2. Why can't I just do `http.get().pipe(routeResponse)`?

Comment: is it necessary to parse JSON before sending with `.pipe`? you could set `application/json` header to the response if the client server can't determinate the type of data.

Comment: @Phoenix yes I brought this up in my question.  It's not necessary, but I still want to know how to do it.

Comment: I have ran into the same problem but isnt this the function scope problem? The callbacks are async so you dont know which order they're in.. As for how you fix it, another function which will passback a wait flag to the callback..

Comment: Instead of parsing I think you'd better stringify the json and give it a utf-8 flag... if you want to pipe objects you'll need some package like arrayStream...